# Bootstrap navbar button not showing up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make my Bootstrap Navbar responsive and when the browser scales down to phone size, the navbar does shrink and hide everything, but the navigation button doesn't show up. Can someone take a look at my code and see if im doing something wrong? Everything seems fine. Thanks for taking a look.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" id="navpad">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">IC</a> <!-- Brand -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <!-- Links -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(Current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <!-- Dropdown -->
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                            aria-expanded="false">Ministerios<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Ministerio 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ministerio 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ministerio 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ministerio 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ministerio 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- /Dropdown -->
                    <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Miembros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /Navbar Collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Navbar Header -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- /Navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `collapse` from the navbar toggle, and set the correct data-target..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            ...
```

http://codeply.com/go/3kSRfMNfmj

Comment: Thanks for this. Although this wasn't the solution, the problem was that the class i typed on the button was "collapse" and it needed to be "collapsed".